# Count the number of max consecutive "a"'s from a string. Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, count

Say that the user inputs:

```
"daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm"
```

How would you go about finding the highest number of consecutive "a" and how would you remove the "a"'s and leave only 2 of them instead of the large number of them before.

I was thinking of appending each letter into a new empty list but i'm not sure if that's correct or what to do after.

I really don't know where to begin with this one but this is what i'm thinking:

1. Ask the user for input.
2. Create an empty list
3. Append each letter from the input into the list

What's next I have no idea.

second edit (something along these lines):

```
sentence = input("Enter your text: ")
new_sentance = " ".join(sentence.split())
length = len(new_sentance)
alist = []
while (length>0):
    alist
print ()
```

Comment: THis is a really neat problem. It just needs a better title. I think that you want to use ***regular expressions*** https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: To get the max number, you would use `max(len(s) for s in re.findall(r'a+', inputString))`. To replace all occurrences of more than 2 "a"s with 2 "a"s, you would use: `output = re.sub(r'a{3,}', "aa", inputString)`.

Comment: This is a fairly interesting question. But you should really post an attempt, so that you can justify more reopen votes

Comment: I have a solution for you now. Please post an attempt so that more users are motivated to vote to reopen, so that I can actually post the solution I have for you

Comment: Just write the code that does your steps 1-3 above. You don't have to show a complete solution, you just have to show a minimal understanding of the problem. In code.

Comment: @Asad Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @askewchan That is only half the question.

Comment: @Asad agreed, vote retracted.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with the input string:

```
input = "daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm"
```

- To get the max consecutive number of occurrences, you would use:

  ```
  max(len(s) for s in re.findall(r'a+', input))
  ```
- To replace only the longest unbroken sequence of "a"s with 2 "a"s,
  you would use:

  ```
  maxMatch = max(re.finditer(r'a+', input), key= lambda m: len(m.group()))
  output = input[:maxMatch.start()] + "aa" + input[maxMatch.end():]
  ```

  First, I obtain an iterable of `MatchObject`s by testing the input string against the regex `a+`, then use `max` to obtain the `MatchObject` with the greatest length. Then, I splice the portion of the original string up to the start of the match, the string "aa", and the portion of the original string after the end of the match to give you your final output.
- To replace *all* occurrences of more than 2 "a"s with 2 "a"s, you
  would use:

  ```
  output = re.sub(r'a{3,}', "aa", input)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

A lower level approach if you don't want to use regular expressions.

```
def count_and_reduce(s, a):
    num = 0
    maxnum = 0
    out = ''
    for c in s:
        if c == a:
            num += 1
            maxnum = max(num, maxnum)
        else:
            num = 0
        if num <= 2:
            out += c

    return maxnum, out
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a couple of regex answers in the comments and the other question, so I'm gonna take a different road. Just getting the count can be done many different ways.

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = 'daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm';
char_groups = groupby(inp, lambda char:char=='a')
counts = [len(list(group)) for char, group in char_groups]
# We know every other element of 'counts' is an 'a' element.
# We just need to know whether to start at zero or one.
# If inp starts with 'a', start at 0. Otherwise start at 1.
max(counts[not inp.startswith('a')::2]) # 11
```

I'm pretty sure both of the regex answers I've seen will replace every string of 'aa+' with two 'a's. If you *only* want to replace the longest string of 'a's with 'aa' and leave the rest alone:

```
char_groups = groupby(inp)
counts = [(char, len(list(group))) for char, group in char_groups]
max_idx = max(range(len(counts)), key=lambda i:counts[i][1] if counts[i][0]=='a' else 0)
result = ''.join(char*count for char, count in counts[:max_idx]) + 'aa' + ''.join(char*count for char, count in counts[max_idx+1:])
# 'daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaafnnasm'
```

Comment: It is possible to accomplish replacement of only the longest sequence much more conveniently using regexen. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Asad I explicitly said I was avoiding regex in my answer *precisely* because I thought you had it covered. So I would certainly hope that any curious reader would also read your answer without being told twice. ;)

Comment: I was talking about this part of your answer: *"I'm pretty sure both of the regex answers I've seen will replace every string of 'aa+' with two 'a's."*. It is possible to accomplish replacement of *only* the longest string using regex as well.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it.

```
s = "daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm"
print(s)
a_len = len(s)
found_a_len = 0
keep_going = True
while a_len>0 and keep_going:
    aas = "a" * a_len
    if aas in s:
        found_a_len = a_len
        keep_going = False
    a_len=a_len -1
print ("max length of a:" , found_a_len)
keep_going = True
while keep_going:
    s=s.replace("aaa","aa")
    if "aaa" not in s:
        keep_going = False
print(s)
```

this outputs:

```
daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm
max length of a: 11
daslakndlaajnjndibniaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaafnnasm
```

Some people might not like my style of coding, but for me, this code is very easy to reason about.

Comment: @dkentre Keeping in mind StackExchange is for future readers of your question and this answer, it would be helpful if you could say what it is about this answer that makes you love it the best. :) Is it more readable for you? Faster? Does it contain a particular style of coding you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import collections

def runLenEncode(s):
    start, i = 0, 0;
    answer = []
    while i<len(s):
        while i<len(s) and s[start]==s[i]:
            i += 1
        answer.append((s[start], i-start))
        start = i
    return answer

def runLenFilter(encoding, thresholds, repLens):
    answer = []
    for char, count in encoding:
        if char in thresholds and count>=thresholds[char]:
            count = repLens[char]
        answer.append(char*count)
    return ''.join(answer)

def maxFilter(encoding, repLens):
    maxCounts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for char, count in encoding:
        if char in repLens and count > maxCounts[char]:
            maxCounts[char] = count
    maxCounts = dict(maxCounts)
    answer = []
    for char, count in encoding:
        if char in repLens and count==maxCounts[char]:
            count = repLens[char]
        answer.append(char*count)
    return ''.join(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('starting')

    s = "daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaaaaaaaaaaafnnasm"
    encoding = runLenEncode(s)
    print("encoding:", encoding)
    thresholds = {'a':3}
    repLens = {'a':2}
    decoded = runLenFilter(encoding, thresholds, repLens)
    print('lenFilter:', decoded)
    filtered = maxFilter(encoding, repLens)
    print("maxFilter:", filtered)

    print('done')
```

**And the output**:

```
$ python3 myFile.py
starting
encoding: [('d', 1), ('a', 1), ('s', 1), ('l', 1), ('a', 1), ('k', 1), ('n', 1), ('d', 1), ('l', 1), ('a', 5), ('j', 1), ('n', 1), ('j', 1), ('n', 1), ('d', 1), ('i', 1), ('b', 1), ('n', 1), ('i', 1), ('a', 3), ('f', 1), ('i', 1), ('j', 1), ('d', 1), ('n', 1), ('f', 1), ('i', 1), ('j', 1), ('d', 1), ('n', 1), ('s', 1), ('i', 1), ('j', 1), ('f', 1), ('n', 1), ('s', 1), ('d', 1), ('i', 1), ('n', 1), ('i', 1), ('f', 1), ('a', 11), ('f', 1), ('n', 2), ('a', 1), ('s', 1), ('m', 1)]
lenFilter: daslakndlaajnjndibniaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaafnnasm
maxFilter: daslakndlaaaaajnjndibniaaafijdnfijdnsijfnsdinifaafnnasm
done
```